# Add new calculated column in a r dataframe based on another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R, called "data" like this

```
c1      c2  c3
A1000   "x" 100 
A1200   "x" 200 
A3000   "y" 150 
A2000   "x" 250 
A3200   "t" 100 
A1000   "e" 250 
A1200   "w" 300
```

I need to create another column, lets say "c4", whith the category name based on following criteria:

```
Code        Name
-----------------------------
A10         "Activity 1"
A12         "Activity 2"
A20         "Activity 3"
other code  "Other activity"
```

Where "code" corresponds to the first 3 characters of column c1 in my data.
I have the following code in R:

```
cat_x <- function(data_x){
  if(substr(data_x, star=1, stop=3) == "A10"){
    return("Activity 1")
  } else if(substr(data_x, star=1, stop=3) == "A12") {
    return("Activity 2")
  } else if(substr(data_x, star=1, stop=3) == "A20") {
    return("Activity 3")
  } else {
    return("Other activity")
  }
  
}

data["c4"] <- cat_x(data$c1)
```

However I get the following error:
"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Please help me to solve this, using my function "cat_x".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sapply`:

```
df$c4 <- sapply(df$c1, cat_x)
```

Your code is not vectorized, so it's not coded to deal with an entire vector at once. Instead it deals with one element at a time, which is how `sapply` will use it.

---

You could also use the library `dplyr` and `case_when` to code this like:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(c4 = case_when( 
    startsWith(c1, "A10") ~ "Activity 1",
    startsWith(c1, "A12") ~ "Activity 2",
    startsWith(c1, "A20") ~ "Activity 3",
    T ~ "Other Activity"))
```

**Output**

```
     c1 c2  c3             c4
1 A1000  x 100     Activity 1
2 A1200  x 200     Activity 2
3 A3000  y 150 Other Activity
4 A2000  x 250     Activity 3
5 A3200  t 100 Other Activity
6 A1000  e 250     Activity 1
7 A1200  w 300     Activity 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!. `sapply` was the perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely better solutions out there but this one is the closest to your own. You first have to create an empty vector of type `character` with the same length as the number of rows in your data frame named `c4`. Then you iterate over the first column whose first three characters you would like to extract and then fill your `c4` in every iteration with the right match.

```
cat_x <- function(data_x){
  c4 <- vector("character", length = nrow(data_x))
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(data_x)) {
    if(substr(data_x[i, 1], star = 1, stop = 3) == "A10"){
      c4[[i]] <- "Activity 1"
    } else if(substr(data_x[i, 1], star = 1, stop = 3) == "A12") {
      c4[[i]] <- "Activity 2"
    } else if(substr(data_x[i, 1], star = 1, stop = 3) == "A20") {
      c4[[i]] <- "Activity 3"
    } else {
      c4[[i]] <- "Other activity"
    }
  }
  cbind(data_x, c4)
}

cat_x(df)

     c1 c2  c3             c4
1 A1000  x 100     Activity 1
2 A1200  x 200     Activity 2
3 A3000  y 150 Other activity
4 A2000  x 250     Activity 3
5 A3200  t 100 Other activity
6 A1000  e 250     Activity 1
7 A1200  w 300     Activity 2
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
                 c1      c2  c3
A1000   x 100 
A1200   x 200 
A3000   y 150 
A2000   x 250 
A3200   t 100 
A1000   e 250 
A1200   w 300")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard merge operation. First make your codes into a data frame and use `dput` to make them easily available:

```
data <- structure(list(c1 = c("A1000", "A1200", "A3000", "A2000", "A3200", 
    "A1000", "A1200"), c2 = c("x", "x", "y", "x", "t", "e", "w"), 
    c3 = c(100L, 200L, 150L, 250L, 100L, 250L, 300L)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, -7L))

codes <- structure(list(Code = c("A10", "A12", "A20"), Name = c("Activity 1", 
    "Activity 2", "Activity 3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Now create a column in `data` that matches the code and merge:

```
data$Code <- substr(data$c1, 1, 3)
data.mrg <- merge(data, codes, all=TRUE)
#   Code    c1 c2  c3       Name
# 1  A10 A1000  x 100 Activity 1
# 2  A10 A1000  e 250 Activity 1
# 3  A12 A1200  x 200 Activity 2
# 4  A12 A1200  w 300 Activity 2
# 5  A20 A2000  x 250 Activity 3
# 6  A30 A3000  y 150       <NA>
# 7  A32 A3200  t 100       <NA>
```

If you want to remove the `Code` column and rename `Name` to `c4`:

```
data.mrg <- data.mrg[, -1]      # Optional to get rid of first column
colnames(data.mrg)[4] <- "c4".  # Optional to change column name
data.mrg
#      c1 c2  c3         c4
# 1 A1000  x 100 Activity 1
# 2 A1000  e 250 Activity 1
# 3 A1200  x 200 Activity 2
# 4 A1200  w 300 Activity 2
# 5 A2000  x 250 Activity 3
# 6 A3000  y 150       <NA>
# 7 A3200  t 100       <NA>
```